# Как проверить наличие ключа в Hashmap

Tags: java-hashmap

Имеется HashMap.требуется проверить существует ли ключ в хэшмап соответствующей заданной строке.Если брать

```
HashMap mp;
String s;
s.equals(mp.get(i));
```

это уже получается сравнение по значению а нужно именно по ключу;

Comment: mp.get(i) != null? mp.containsKey(i) ? чем это не подходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как говорится в [ответе на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3626779/2881286)

Если значение не может быть `null`:

```
Foo value = map.get(key);
if (value != null) {
    ...
} else {
    // такого ключа нет
}
```

Иначе, вы можете просто проверить, что такой ключ существует, если получили значение `null`:

```
Foo value = map.get(key);
if (value != null) {
    ...
} else {
    // Ключ может быть...
    if (map.containsKey(key)) {
       // Ключ присутствует, но значение null
    } else {
       // Определенно нет ключа
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
if (mp.containsKey(s))
{
    // в mp содержится ключ s
}
```

[подробнее в документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29)